# Exchange 2010 SP3 upgrade fails during preparation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade our Exchange 2010 SP1 server to SP3 in preparation of installing a new Exchange 2013 server to take over, which requires SP3 on the 2010 machine to be able to migrate. While all prerequisite checks succeed (1 warning related to an update for failover clustering not being installed, which I'm not using anyway) I then get the following error right away 10 seconds after starting the upgrade:

[image]

The relevant part of the setup log seems to be (complete failing log [here](http://pastebin.com/w9aMdERL)):

```
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] Creating templates
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] Entering CAtomOrgCtChildren::ScUpdateTemplates
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] Attempt to get an exclusive access to the directory
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] Checking if the user has enough persmissions to update templates.
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] Entering ScHavePermissionToCreateDSObject
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2]  Status code check (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\libs\ds\x_dob.cxx:3370)
           Error code 0X8000500D (20493): This property can't be found in the cache.
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] Leaving ScHavePermissionToCreateDSObject
[12-06-2013 01:30:12.0483] [2] User has enough permissions to update templates.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2]  Status code check (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\libs\ds\x_dob.cxx:1200)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2]  CAtomOrgCtChildren::ScUpdateTemplates - failed to get a list of templates (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\udog\exsetdata\components\server\a_orgctchildren.cxx:1205)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2]  CAtomOrgCtChildren::ScUpdateTemplates (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\udog\exsetdata\components\server\a_orgctchildren.cxx:1336)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2] Leaving CAtomOrgCtChildren::ScUpdateTemplates
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2]  CAtomOrgCtChildren::ScAddDSObjects (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\udog\exsetdata\components\server\a_orgctchildren.cxx:215)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2] Leaving CAtomOrgCtChildren::ScAddDSObjects
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2]  CBaseAtom::ScRefreshDSObjects (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\udog\setupbase\basecomp\baseatom.cxx:1478)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2] mode = 'Reinstall' (61955) CBaseAtom::ScSetup (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\udog\setupbase\basecomp\baseatom.cxx:537)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2]  ScSetupAtom (f:\14.03.0123\sources\dev\admin\src\udog\exsetdata\exsetds.cxx:882)
           Error code 0X80072020 (8224): An operations error occurred.
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0806] [2] Leaving ScSetupAtom
[12-06-2013 01:30:15.0822] [2] [ERROR] An error occurred with error code '2147950624' and message 'An operations error occurred.'.
[12-06-2013 01:30:16.0259] [1] The following 1 error(s) occurred during task execution:
[12-06-2013 01:30:16.0259] [1] 0.  ErrorRecord: An error occurred with error code '2147950624' and message 'An operations error occurred.'.
[12-06-2013 01:30:16.0259] [1] 0.  ErrorRecord: Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Deployment.ExsetdataException: An error occurred with error code '2147950624' and message 'An operations error occurred.'.
```

I'm completely stuck on what is actually failing now, and why. There were domain controllers cleanly removed from the network recently, but they were never relevant - all FSMO roles and GC remained on the srv-003 server and the other ones were cleanly demoted.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have an Exchange DAG?

Comment: Nope, single site single server single organization single everything - as simple as they come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I managed to get it to install. My pre-update situation was:

- 2 Windows 2008R2 Domain Controllers
- One of them running Exchange 2010 SP1

I was also planning to replace the 2 existing domain controllers with Windows 2012 R2 along the way. When I couldn't update to SP2 or SP3, eventually I just installed the first new Windows 2012 R2 anyway, made it a full domain controller and transferred all the FSMO roles. From this moment on, I could successfully run `setup /PrepareAD` on the Exchange 2010 box and install service pack 3.

I **think** the underlying reason is that I had toyed with Windows 2012 before, and stopped that upgrade route when I didn't have time for it and 2k12R2 was about to be released anyway. I **did** however do the `forestprep` and `domainprep` updates to the AD schema at the time. As such I suspect the installer was confused about finding a Win2k12-prepared AD, while still at 2k8R2 functional levels with 2k8R2 FSMO holders.

Note that I obviously didn't raise the functional levels yet since there are still 2k8R2 DCs in the domain - I just transferred the FSMO routes since the logs show it was communicating with the Schema Master all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the installer is complaining about missing or damaged files in the install directory. Redownload the patch, check the md5, and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried taking 'the long route' by downloading and installing SP2 first, and it's giving the same error so this is not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the errors again, it looks like it's trying to update some Active Directory objects but it's failing. Try running `setup /PrepareSchema`. Make sure you are a member of the `Schema Admins` group.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the command ran successfully, I'll try the SP3 upgrade itself again when I have a chance later on (don't have time right now to babysit it :)

Comment: Following up, the installer still fails. Tried running `setup /PrepareAD` and it fails identically (is essentially the same anyway). Following [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e9a61e25-ebfa-4767-8128-2912323734a9/exchange-2010-sp1-on-server-2008-sp2-hangs-on-preparead-organization-prep) I tried to run `/PrepareAD` from my FSMO Schema Master directly, and same error. I'm wondering now whether there's something corrupted in AD at all but nothing to be found in event logs  :(